# My wordpress site initial loading is too slow.How to improve?

Tags: php, wordpress, load-time

I've hosted a wordpress site [kerala.letmeshare.org](http://kerala.letmeshare.org). But it takes too much time for loading. It doesn't seem to be a network issue. Static pages on the same domain get loaded as usual (faster). What might be the reason?

I analyzed using the Performance Profiler Plugin and the following reports were generated.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**How can i improve perfomance.
I contacted my hosting provider,they tested well, there is no problem with Server load time,networs and all.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons May be:

Maybe your PHP is running per CGI or FastCGI in a separate process that shuts down after a while of inactivity. Does it change if you register at an [uptime monitoring service](http://uptime.openacs.org/uptime/about.adp)? A cache plugin like [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) may help too.

One of the typical reasons for such behavior is if you are loading RSS feeds in front-end. Their cache expires and you get very long pause next time, because they need to be fetched over network.

Try to replicate it on local server, it will give you more options for troubleshooting - ultimate one being making full profiler dump (with xdebug for example) and analyzing it.

## Page Speed Optimization

- This page makes 30 parallelizable requests to kerala.letmeshare.org (Reduce them)
- Cachea resources have a short freshness lifetime.
- http://kerala.letmeshare.org/wp-content/themes/TheTravelTheme/includes/timthumb.php?src=http://kerala.letmeshare.org/....   [Remove these loops - Request again requesting looping same hostname]
- Size of Homepage 1.2 MB [Reduce Size - Optimize Images]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wp total cache plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS then you need to change the application pool recycling settings to disable the timeout

On your appserver, open IIS Manager

In the left pane (Connections), select Application Pools.

In the middle pane (Application Pools), select AppPool.

In the right pane (Actions), select Edit Application Pool > Recycling… (not the Recycle… task).

In the Recycling Conditions window, ensure all checkboxes are cleared (unchecked).

Click Next, then Finish.

Again in the right pane (Actions), select Edit Application Pool > Advanced Settings…

In the Advanced Settings window, under Process Model, set Idle Time-out (minutes) to zero (0).

Click OK

Back in the left pane (Connections), select Sites.

Select the Default Web Site

In the right pane (Actions), select Manage Web Site > Advanced Settings…

In the Advanced Settings window, under Connection Limits, set Connection Time-out to zero (0).

Save the setting changes.

Restart IIS.